# Case statement In SQL on Dimension level

Tags: sql, case

I have a Table in sql with data

| Customer | Card Type |
| --- | --- |
| Abc | Debit |
| Abc | Credit |
| Cde | Debit |
| Edg | Credit |
| Edg | Credit |

I need to find the Dualflag if a customer is using both the cards then yes else no.

I tried row number by grouping data on customer but then unable to proceed with case statement when row number is greater than 1 because in that case it won't reflect on where row number is one for same customer.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: BTW, `case` is an _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Comment: I guess using `DENSE_RANK` will do, for example https://dbfiddle.uk/Z3dw7EzF, but must be supported by your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data:

```
create table #table
(
    Customer varchar(3),
    [Card Type] varchar(6)
)

insert into #table values
('Abc','Debit'),
('Abc','Credit'),
('Cde','Debit'),
('Edg','Credit'),
('Edg','Credit')
```

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to return just those Customers who are using two distinct different `Card Type`s:

```
select
    Customer
from #table
group by Customer
having count(distinct [Card Type]) = 2
```

If you want to return all your records and include a flag for Customers using 2 `Card Type`s, then:

```
select
    a.*,
    case when b.Customer is null then 'false' else 'true' end as UsingTwoCardTypes
from #table a
left join
(
    select
        Customer
    from #table
    group by Customer
    having count(distinct [Card Type]) = 2
) b on a.Customer = b.Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions `min()` and `max()` to determine whether a customer has both card types or not :

```
with cte as (
  select *, min(Card_Type) over (partition by Customer) as min_card_type,
          max(Card_Type) over (partition by Customer) as max_card_type
  from mytable
)
select Customer, Card_Type, case when min_card_type <> max_card_type then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Dualflag
from cte;
```

Results :

```
Customer    Card_Type   Dualflag
Abc         Debit       Yes
Abc         Credit      Yes
Cde         Debit       No
Edg         Credit      No
Edg         Credit      No
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/p_lD9qB2)